# How hard is to invert the function that computes the middle-bits of (x^2)?

Tags: one-way-function, function-evaluation

I'm designing a function f that should be moderately hard to invert and very fast to evaluate in a modern CPU. The function will be used in a proof-of-work function.

I've read that the middle-bits of multiplication are the harder bits to obtain, so I suspect that they are the hardest to invert.

Let $f(x) = ((x^2) >> 16)$ where $x$ is 32-bits and $f(x)$ is truncated to 32-bts, and the multiplication is carried on a 64-bit architecture.

(alternatively one could use $f(x) = ((2^{32}-x-1)*x) >> 16 )$

Suppose that, since $f$ may not be bijective, any pre-image (if exists) is accepted.
Suppose also that there is no enough memory or time to precompute $f^{-1}$ for all possible $f(x)$ values (although there might be some memory/time to precompute a much smaller table)

Again, this is not a strict crypto question. In this context "hard" does not mean cryptographically hard. I'm asking approximately how hard it is, measured in number of instructions of a standard computer (with a standard instruction set). A bound on the number of any operation would be great.

I'm posting here because the question does not fit well in theoretical computer science not in programming stack-exchanges.

Maybe there is a paper that describes this?

Comment: Also I'm interested in the number of logic gates it takes to implement the inversion circuit, as compared to the number of logic gates it takes to compute f.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably not secure enough for a proof of work.  I'll outline some attacks, of increasing sophistication/complexity and increasing effectiveness (decreasing runtime).

### Brute force

The obvious attack is brute force: enumerate all $2^{32}$ possible inputs and check to find the first that produces the desired output.  This takes $2^{32}$ time.  I'm sure you already knew about this attack, and based on your question, it sounds like this is acceptable in your application.

### Time-space tradeoff

You can use Hellman's time-space tradeoffs (or rainbow tables, the hyped-up version of that) to solve preimages.  You have to do a $2^{32}$-step precomputation to build up the table.  The table is of size about $2^{22}$.  After you've built up the table, you can find a preimage of $f(x)$ in about $2^{22}$ steps of computation.

Thus, after a one-time precomputation that probably takes a few minutes or at most hours, you can invert the function in a few seconds, using a few tens of megabytes of storage.

### Guess the high bits and take a square root in the integers

There's a cleverer attack, which will find the preimage using at most $2^{16}$ simple steps of arithmetic (often quite a bit faster).  This will probably run in much less than a second, maybe at little as milliseconds to find a preimage.

We can write any 64-bit integer in the form $\alpha \cdot 2^{48} + \beta \cdot 2^{16} + \gamma$, where $\alpha$ is a 16-bit integer, $\beta$ a 32-bit integer, and $\gamma$ a 16-bit integer (i.e., $0 \le \alpha,\gamma < 2^{16}$ and $0 \le \beta < 2^{32}$).  Now we don't know the value of $x^2$, but $x^2$ is a 64-bit integer and we know its middle bits, so we can write it in the form

$$x^2 = \alpha \cdot 2^{48} + \beta \cdot 2^{16} + \gamma$$

where we know $\beta$ ($\beta$ is just the output of your hash function) but we don't know $\alpha,\gamma$.

Now iterate over all possible values of $\alpha$.  For each guess at $\alpha$, form the value

$$y = \alpha \cdot 2^{48} + \beta \cdot 2^{16} + 2^{16}-1,$$

take the square root of $y$ in the integers, and round down to an integer.  Let $x'$ denote the result, i.e., $x' = \lfloor \sqrt{y} \rfloor$.  Then check whether $x'$ is the desired preimage, i.e., whether $f(x') = \beta$.

I claim that this attack requires at most $2^{16}$ steps.  There are only $2^{16}$ possible values of $\alpha$, so we do at most $2^{16}$ iterations.  Moreover, in the iteration where we've guessed the value of $\alpha$ correctly, I claim we will successfully recover the preimage $x$.  Let me explain why.  First, the 64-bit integer $y$ will be very close to the 64-bit integer $x^2$: $y - x^2 < 2^{16}$.  Therefore, when you take the square-root, $\sqrt{y}$ will be very close to $\sqrt{x^2}=x$.  How close?  Well, notice that $(x+1)^2 \approx x^2 + 2x + 1$, so for 32-bit values of $x$, consecutive squares will be about $2^{32}$ apart from each other.  That's much larger than the gap between $y$ and $x^2$, so $y$ will be much closer to $x^2$ than to $(x-1)^2$ or $(x+1)^2$.  Thus, taking the square root of $y$ and rounding to the nearest integer will return $x$, not $x-1$ or $x+1$ or anything else (unless $x$ is extremely small, say $x < 2^{14}$, which has very low probability and thus can be ignored).

This means that this attack is guaranteed to succeed after at most $2^{16}$ iterations.

It turns out that not all values of $\alpha$ are equally likely; when $x$ is uniformly distributed, the upper 16 bits of $x^2$ are biased towards small values.  Therefore, if you iterate over all values of $\alpha$ in the sequence $0,1,2,3,\dots,2^{16}-1$, you are unusually likely to succeed early.  The average number of iterations until success is $2^{16}/3$, so the attack is about $3\times$ faster than you might expect based upon a worst-case analysis.

Comment: I like this approach; actually, instead of rounding to the nearing integer, you'd select $y = \alpha \cdot 2^{48} + \beta \cdot 2^{16} + 2^{16}-1$, give it to your FPU to sqrt, and then round down the result.  If that integer doesn't hash to the correct value, you know your guess for the upper 16 bits was incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Say $m$ is the number and $h=f(m)$ it will be pretty easy to find $m'$ (not necessarily equal to $m$) such that $f(m)=f(m')$ on a modern computer.

**Brute Force**
The output of $f(m)$ is 32 bits. The following python function will do it

```
def find_collision(val):
  while True:
    test = random.getrandbits(32)
    target = ((test*test) >> 16) & 0xffffffff)
    if target == val:
      return test
```

It will take around $2^{32}$ loop iterations to find a correct value. I'll leave taking that down to individual instructions to you. Random number should be cheap if the OS has a random number generator (on linux it would be as easy as reading 4 bytes from /dev/urandom).

Remember this is simply a brute force attack. It is very possible that a better attack works too in which case even if you scale up to 160 bit numbers it could still be easy to invert.

Comment: The brute-force attack is obviously a upper bound in the number of computations. It does not help me much to known how much time an attacker will require to invert it.

Comment: *cleaned up some comments that were no longer needed*

Answer (score 4):

Someone can find a preimage (or prove that there is no such preimage) with about $2^{20}$ trial squares, and no precomputed storage.  ACtually, I believe that the below procedure will actually achieve $2^{18}$ trial squares; that requires closer analysis than I feel like at the moment.

Here is the key observation that we can take advantage of to show this:

If we have a guess $X$ of $A \ge 16$ bits of the lsbits of the preimage, and that guess has precisely $B < A-1$ bits of zeros at the bottom (i.e. bit $B$ is the lowest '1' bit of $X$), then that completely determines the lower $A+B-15$ bits of the hash output; in addition, we can set or clear bit $A+B-15$ of the hash output by setting/clearing bit $A$ of the preimage.

It is easy to verify this by examining the binomial expansion of $(X+\Delta)^2$

Here is how we can use this observation: if we have a 16 bit guess $X$ of the preimage (other than 0x0000 or 0x8000; those violate the $B<A-1$ assumption), then we determine $B$ the number of least significant zero bits.

We first check the hash of $X$; if the lower $B+1$ bits of that output do not agree with the target image, then we know that $X$ cannot be the lower 16 bits of a preimage.

Assuming that the lower $B+1$ bits are correct, then scan from bit 16 updates; check to see if bit $B+1+i$ of the hash is correct; if it is not, then set bit $16+i$ of $X$, and recompute the hash.

This loop will end when either we run out of bits in the target hash, or $16+i = 32$ (and we have no more bits we can set).  If we run out of bits in the target hash, then we have a preimage $X$.  If we run out of bits in the preimage, check if the hash is precisely the target we're looking for; if not, then we've proven that the original $X$ cannot have been the lower 16 bits of the preimage.

The above loop will require at most $17$ hashes (the initial hash of $X$, and one hash for every one of the 16 upper bits of the preimage).

Perform this procedure for every 16 bit initial value of $X$ other than 0x000 and 0x8000; that requires a maximum of $17 \times (2^{16}-2) \approx 2^{20}$ hashes.

To do an exhaustive search also requires the examination of the 0x0000 and 0x8000 preimages; those can be special cased.